# Deducing the hairy ball theorem from inverse function theorem.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, spheres

The following results easily follows from inverse function theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $p\in U$ and $X:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ a $\mathcal{C}^k(U,\mathbb{R}^n)$-vector-field with $k\geqslant 1$. If $X(p)$ is nonzero, there exists $V$ an open neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $W$ an open neighborhood of $p$ in $U$ and $f:V\rightarrow W$ a $\mathcal{C}^k$-diffeomorphism such that $f(0)=p$ and $f^*X\equiv X(p)$.

I am strongly convinced that from there one can establish the following:

> **Theorem.** A $\mathcal{C}^1$-vector-field on $\mathbb{S}^2$ vanishes at at least one point.

Assume there exists $v$ a $\mathcal{C}^1$-vector-field on $\mathbb{S}^2$ that does not vanish on $\mathbb{S}^2$. Let $p_N:\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{N\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be the stereographic projection of north pole onto the equatorial plane. Then, $w_N:=p_N\circ v$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$-vector field of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that does not vanish. Hence, there exists a $\mathcal{C}^1$-diffeomorphism from an open neighborhood of $0$ onto an open neighborhood of $S$ such that $f^*v$ is constant. I cannot proceed any further from here.

My goal is to deduce hairy ball theorem from the inverse function theorem. Thus, I would like to avoid arguments using the fundamental group of $\mathbb{S}^1$ and degree theory.

Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: But the inverse function theorem is a local theorem whereas the hairy ball theorem is global. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jacky You're not. You cannot deduce any global fact from this.

Comment: You could try recreating Milnor's proof using the change of variables theorem. Assume you have a nowhere zero vector field, extend to the ball in a smooth way, define a mapping and use change of variables to compute the volume of the image.